# How can I achieve this annotation effect?

Tags: arrows, annotations

I am reading a programming book, and I notice a very intuitive use of annotations to explain syntax,

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is another example

[image]

I would like to achieve a similar effect for my own work. Is there an easy way of doing this ?

Comment: Have you tried tikz?

Comment: Yes , I was wondering if there is a package that makes achieving the effect easy.